# Proof that the Euler phi function is multiplicative using cyclic group argument

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups, totient-function

I would like to know if this reasoning is sound. This comes from exercise 2.21 in Rotman's intro to group theory. The goal is to show $\phi(rs)=\phi(r)\phi(s)$.

I was able to show that if $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, then $a^k$ , an element of $G$, is a generator iff $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime: thus there are $\phi(n)$ generators of $G$. (I should mention $\phi(n)$ = the number of integers $x$ where $1\leq x< n$ such that $x$ and $n$ are relatively prime). Next, that if the order of $G$ is $rs$, where $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime, then there are unique subgroups of $G$ of order $r$ and $s$. These subgroups are those generated by $b$ and $c$, where $b=a^r$ , $c=a^s$ , the order of $b$ is $s$, and the order of $c$ is $r$. Further, $bc=a^{(r+s)}$ is a generator of $G$ (since if $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime, then $r+s$ is relatively prime with $rs$).
Everything up until now I'm fine with, the following is what I want to prove. Now $b$ has $\phi(s)$ many generators, and $c$ has $\phi(r)$ many. That means there are $\phi(s)$ many integers $x$ such that $a$ is in $G$ and $a^x = b$, and $\phi(r)$ many integers $y$ such that $a^y = c$. So ostensibly there are $\phi(r)\phi(s)$ combinations $a^{(x+y)} = bc$, and thus there are $\phi(r)\phi(s)$ generators of $G$. But we know there are $\phi(rs)$ generators of $G$, so $\phi(rs)=\phi(r)\phi(s)$

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $\varphi$ is multiplicative is a corollary of the chinese remainder theorem, namely that the rings $\mathbb Z_{nm}$ and $\mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_m$ are isomorphic when $(n,m)=1$. This is because the first has $\varphi(nm)$ invertible elements while the second has $\varphi(n)\varphi(m)$ invertible elements.

Comment: It would be better if your title were "Proof that the Euler phi function is multiplicative ...". Multiplicity in the context of the Euler phi function refers to the number of solutions to an equation such as $\phi(n)=20$ which has multiplicity 5, i.e. the five solutions, $n=${25, 33, 44, 50, 66}. See, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientValenceFunction.html

Comment: I've done the above suggested edit myself....